# Define custom authorizer for all functions (AWS + Serverless)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I have been creating an application using serverless framework with AWS as my cloud provider. I have some HTTP routes for creating an user, listing users, etc.

I'm using HTTP v2:

```
httpApi:
    authorizers:
      authAuthorizer:
        type: request
        functionName: authAuthorizer
```

But then, I need to define the custom authorizer for each endpoint I have:

```
createUser:
  handler: src/createUser.main
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: POST
        path: /users
        authorizer:
          name: authAuthorizer
```

Would be possible to setup a custom authorizer for the whole gateway and then I just specify which route I don't want to be protected? This would prevent mistakes such as forgetting to add the authorization to important routes and turning then into public.

I've searched all over and couldn't find anything related to.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible to set up a custom authorizer..

Try configure authorizers on `provider.httpApi.authorizers` in your `serverless.yml` file. You can then configure endpoints that are expected to have restricted access by specifying the `authorizer` property in the `events` section of your function definition.

For example, the `/private` route is protected by the `authAuthorizer` authorizer, so only authorized users can access it.

```
httpApi:
  authorizers:
    authAuthorizer:
      type: request
      functionName: authAuthorizer

  routes:
    - path: /public
      method: GET
      authorizer: NONE
      function: publicFunction

    - path: /private
      method: GET
      authorizer: authAuthorizer
      function: privateFunction
```

More details here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api

**Edit**:
I think setting a default authorizer for the whole gateway is not directly supported in AWS API Gateway with the serverless framework. Each endpoint still needs to explicitly specify the authorizer.

However, if you would like to avoid specifying an authorizer for each of the private functions, I could suggest a workaround: group multiple routes under a single function, and specify the authorizer for that function, so effectively applying it to multiple routes at once. For example using a wildcard in the `path` property of the endpoint definition

```yaml
functions:
  privateFunctions:
    handler: src/privateFunctions.main
    events:
      - httpApi:
          method: GET
          path: /private/*
          authorizer:
            name: authAuthorizer
```

Comment: Yep, I know that. What I want is to avoid specifying an authorizer for each of the private functions. I would like to have private by default. In your case, you still need to tell functions to use an authorizer with "authorizer: authAuthorizer"

Comment: Try my workaround if it works

Answer (score 0):

What we do in AWS **SAM**, we have a *root api*, that attached with authorization mechanism. And in **Lambda** function, we mention the *root api*'s **ID** to the lambda's *api event*. As, *root api* is **authorized**, all other lambdas using *root api* as its api, lambda become **authorized** by default, and when we need a **public api**, we mention the *root api*'s ID to the lambda's *api even*t and do an explicit mention Authorizer is **None** to rhe lambda.